# pyenv pollute my current python environment

Tags: pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

my OS: `macOS Big Sur 11.5.1 (20G80)`
cpu Arch: `Intel cpu, amd64`
pyenv: `2.3.20`
Python version: 3.11.4
c compiler info:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I install `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` using `brew`

```py
brew install pyenv
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
```

I'm using fish-shell, so after installing, I put `pyenv init - | source` in to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` and source it, I didn't change `PYENV_ROOT`, so `PYENV_ROOT` defaults to `$HOME/.pyenv`.

Then I try the following operations

```bash
# create virtual environment
pyenv virtualenv 3.8 jarvis

# enter virtual environment
pyenv activate jarvis

# deactivate virtual environment
pyenv deactivate
```

for now, everything seems works fine
[image: active pyenv]

---

But there is a problem: if I check the `python3`/`pip3`'s location, they are all under `/Users/bruce/.pyenv/shims/` even if I didn't activate the virtual environment, which is not right.

[image]

Even more wierder is: the `pip3` itself was installed at `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`(screenshot above), but isn't it should be in `~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/envs/jarvis/lib/python3.8/site-packages`?(screenshot below)
[image]

In fact I can accept using the `python3` and `pip3` in pyenv location even I didn't enter(activate) the virtual environment, but the point is: it separates the `pip3` and pip package installation location, on one hand, `which pip3` says the `pip3` is located at `/Users/bruce/.pyenv/shims/pip3`, on the other hand, `pip3 --version` says `pip3` is at `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip`, so where on earth does the pip located at?